# Copy the text content of a text file via file open

Tags: javascript, html, filereader

My project is something like a C++ web-based IDE and im working on its open button which will open a text file and append the text to its `contenteditable div`. When i click on the `choose file button` i want to

1. get the contents of the text file chosen like how clipboard copying does it
2. append the copied text to the contenteditable div like how pasting does it

   2.1 provided `setCaret` function which will set the caret position at the start of the contenteditable div

   2.2 provided `pasteTextAtCaret` function which will start pasting the event at the current caret position

I want it to work like copy and paste events because this events cause no errors in my code and to save time debugging.

```
function readSingleFile(evt) {

            var f = evt.target.files[0];
            console.log(f);

            if (!f) {
                alert("Failed to load file");
                   return;
            } 

            if (f.name.indexOf('.txt') == -1) {
                alert(f.name + " is not a valid text file.");
                return;     
            }    

            var r = new FileReader();
            r.onload = function(e) { 

            setCaret(false, 0);
                    //copy here
            pasteTextAtCaret(copied_text);



          }
          r.readAsText(f);
}

function setCaret(colPosition, divPos) {
            alert('calllled');
            var range = document.createRange();
            var sel = window.getSelection();
            range.selectNodeContents($('#board')[divPos]);
            range.collapse(colPosition);
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);//setting the caret position
}    

function pasteTextAtCaret(text) {
            alert('pasted');
            var sel, range;
            if (window.getSelection) {
                sel = window.getSelection();
                if (sel.getRangeAt && sel.rangeCount) {
                    range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
                    range.deleteContents();

                    var textNode = document.createTextNode(text);
                    range.insertNode(textNode);

                    range = range.cloneRange();
                    range.setStartAfter(textNode);
                    range.collapse(false);
                    sel.removeAllRanges();
                    sel.addRange(range);                    

                }//if
            }//if 

            else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
                document.selection.createRange().text = text;
            }//else if
}

document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change', readSingleFile, false);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/88vtR/26/

Answer (score 0):

Or just make it easy with php

```
<?php
$file = "YourFile.txt";
$read = file_get_contents($file);
echo $read;
?>
```